# Are there any way to let a Set type converted to Array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, set

I try to find a way to convert a Set to Array intelligently.
For example:

I have a Set which length is 0 to 3(means the set maybe["a","b","c"] or ["a","b"] or ["a"] or [])

And then I want to get a appropriate Array.

Like:
the Set                            --> the Array

["a","b","c"]   -> ["a","b","c"](Order is not cared)

["a","b"]  -> ["a","b",""]     (the nil String must be the last appended)

["b"] -> ["b","",""]

[""] -> ["","",""]

How can I get this ? Anybody can help me?

Comment: Do you always know the size of the set? Because I don't think Swift supports a fixed size Set

Comment: This size of Set only can be 0 to 3 . It is a Set we have got . Only the Array is a fixed size one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in a single operation.

First you need to convert the set to an array and then you need to pad the array to the required length

```
let mySet = Set(["a", "b", "a"])
var myArray = Array(mySet)


for var index=myArray.count;index<3;index++ {
    myArray.append("")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the set will only be size of 0..3, then convert it to an array and pad it:

```
var mySet = Set<String>() // A set with 0..3 size

var myArray = Array(mySet)
for var i=0;i<3-mySet.count;i++ {
    myArray.append("") // fill the array till size 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have accepted Paulw11's answer and ur answer is correct too.But it is similar to Paulw11's and his answer is more early than urs, sorry.